# Splitting Page with Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am looking to develop a page for a schedule app and UI should be like 
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mlOF.png
    I got this tab UI from get bootstrap.com Now I am good with tabs working as expected however on the Gantt Tab I am looking to have a split page where I can http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos/toggle_alternate_layouts2.html
    it works fine when I put the div at Body level but when I put the div under Tab

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="SchedulerMainApp">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My Client</title>
    <link href="../CSS/layout-default-latest.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Helper.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/MainController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
                var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
            });
            $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.type === 'drop') {
                    var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
                    de = $('#' + data).detach();
                    de.appendTo($(this));
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Left Side Bar Navigation Bar -->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" ng-controller="SideBarController">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeLeftNav()">&times;</a>
        <a id='SideBarFirstoption' ng-click="ShowAlert('hello');" href="#">{{Action}}</a>
        <a href="#">{{Services}}</a>
        <a href="#">{{Clients}}</a>
        <a href="#">{{Contact}}</a>
    </div>
    <div>

        <div id="main" ng-controller='MainController'>
            <h2>Dynamic Menu Bar</h2>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">
                        <div id='MainContent'>
                            <span style="font-size:15px;cursor:pointer" onclick="HideShowNavBar()">&#9776; Menu</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#ScheduleGanttPage" onclick="closeLeftNav()">{{ScheduleGanttTab}}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#TimeManagement" onclick="closeLeftNav()">{{TimeManagementTab}}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Reports" onclick="closeLeftNav()">{{ReportsTab}}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#KPIsMonitor" onclick="closeLeftNav()">{{KPIsMonitorTab}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <h3>HOME</h3>
                    <span onclick="closeLeftNav()">
                        Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
                        <br /> {{name}}
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div id="ScheduleGanttPage" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Schedule</h3>
                    <table id="#our_table" border="1" class="table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>head1</th>
                            <th>head1</th>
                            <th>head1</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">aaa</span></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="TimeManagement" class="tab-pane fade">
                </div>
                <div id="Reports" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 Menu 3 </p>
                </div>
                <div id="KPIsMonitor" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 Menu 4 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--
                <span onclick="closeLeftNav()">
                    <div id='MenuBars' ng-controller='MenuBarController'>
                        <div id='mainmenuFile' class="dropdown" >
                            <button class="dropbtn">File</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a id='MainMenuFileOpen' href="#">Open</a>
                                <a id='MainMenuFileSave'  href="#">Save</a>
                                <a id='MainMenuFileExit'  href="#">Exit</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id='mainmenuFile' class="dropdown">
                            <button class="dropbtn">Edit</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                                <a id='MainMenuEditCut' href="#">Cut</a>
                                <a id='MainMenuEditCopy'  href="#">Copy</a>
                                <a id='MainMenuEditPaste'  href="#">Paste</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <br/>
                <div id='MainContent' ng-controller='MainController'>
                    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="HideShowNavBar()">&#9776; Menu</span>
                </div>
                -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>

sidebarcontroller.js
MySchedulerApp.controller('SideBarController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Action = 'Action';
    $scope.Services = 'Services';
    $scope.Clients = 'Clients';
    $scope.Contact = 'Contact';

    (function () {
        $(function () {
            var SideBAR;
            SideBAR = (function () {
                function SideBAR() { }

                SideBAR.prototype.expandMyMenu = function () {
                    return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-menu-expanded");
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.collapseMyMenu = function () {
                    return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-expanded").addClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed");
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.showMenuTexts = function () {
                    return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").show();
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.hideMenuTexts = function () {
                    return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").hide();
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.showActiveSubMenu = function () {
                    $("li.active ul.level2").show();
                    return $("li.active a.expandable").css({
                        width: "100%"
                    });
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.hideActiveSubMenu = function () {
                    return $("li.active ul.level2").hide();
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.adjustPaddingOnExpand = function () {
                    $("ul.level1 li a.expandable").css({
                        padding: "1px 4px 4px 0px"
                    });
                    return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                        padding: "1px 4px 4px 4px"
                    });
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse = function () {
                    $("ul.nbs-level1 li a.expandable").css({
                        padding: "4px 4px 4px 0px"
                    });
                    return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                        padding: "4px"
                    });
                };

                SideBAR.prototype.ignite = function () {
                    return (function (instance) {
                        return $("#justify-icon").click(function (e) {
                            if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed")) {
                                instance.adjustPaddingOnExpand();
                                instance.expandMyMenu();
                                instance.showMenuTexts();
                                instance.showActiveSubMenu();
                                $(this).css({
                                    color: "#000"
                                });
                            } else if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-expanded")) {
                                instance.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse();
                                instance.collapseMyMenu();
                                instance.hideMenuTexts();
                                instance.hideActiveSubMenu();
                                $(this).css({
                                    color: "#FFF"
                                });
                            }
                            return false;
                        });
                    })(this);
                };

                return SideBAR;

            })();
            return (new SideBAR).ignite();
        });

    }).call(this);
});

/* MainApp.controller('SideBarController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Action = 'MyAction';
    $scope.Services = 'MyServices';
    $scope.Clients = 'MyClients';
    $scope.Contact = 'MyContact';
    $scope.name = 'varun Sharma';
}); */

maincontroller.cs
var myApp = angular.module("SchedulerMainApp", [])
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.PageTitle = 'Top Page';
        $scope.name = 'Varun Sharma1';
        $scope.ScheduleGanttTab = 'Schedule Gantt';
        $scope.TimeManagementTab = 'Time Management';
        $scope.ReportsTab = 'Reports';
        $scope.KPIsMonitorTab = 'KPIs Monitor';
        $scope.content = 'Hello World';
    });



helper.js
var SideBarVisible = false;
Action = 'MyAction';

function openLeftNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    SideBarVisible = true;
}

function closeLeftNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    SideBarVisible = false;
}

function HideShowNavBar() {
    if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width == '' || document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width == '0px') {
        openLeftNav();
    }
    else {
        closeLeftNav();
    }
}

function ShowAlert(message) {
    alert(message);
};

bootstrap.min.css from getbootstrap.com

jquery.layout-latest.js (185 KB – 55 KB GZip) -- from http://layout.jquery-dev.com/downloads.cfm
layout-default-latest.css – Layout default-styles (optional) -- from http://layout.jquery-dev.com/downloads.cfm

styles.css

.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
}

.left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

        .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus {
            color: #f1f1f1;
        }

    .sidenav .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }


/*
        #main {
           transition: margin-left .5s;
           padding: 16px;
        }
        */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

        .sidenav a {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
}

h1 {
    font-size: 130%;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 110%;
    margin: 0.75em 0 0.5em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0.25em;
}

p {
    margin: 0.35em 0;
}

ol, ul, li {
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

pre {
    white-space: pre;
    color: #060;
    font: 90% Courier New,monospace;
    margin: 0.75em;
}

kbd {
    font: 90% Courier New,monospace;
    color: #060;
}

code {
    font: 100% Courier New,monospace;
    color: #050;
}

em {
    color: #833;
    font-weight: bold;
}

dt {
    color: #336;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.25em 0;
}

dd {
    margin: 0.25em 2em 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: When i save the layout in a new file. test.html as below it works great

Comment: can you make a plunker of the problem?  Since it works when not nested under tab, it sounds like it could be a CSS problem

Comment: Hi Varun and welcome to SO! If you wish to add more information to a question, you can do so by editing the question. This is often more appreciated than comments. Also have a look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on providing code to the community.